# JavaScript rotation is wrong after translating

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity.js

I'm using Velocity.js for animation.

I'm first translating and rotating an object. After the animation is complete I need to rotate the object by an additional 360 degrees.

The problem is that during the second animation the rotation axis is off. Instead of rotating around the center the object rotates around its original point.

```
$.Velocity( obj, "stop" );
$.Velocity( obj,
              {translateX: pos, rotateZ: rotation + 'deg'},
              {duration: 1000, complete: function() {
                  $.Velocity( obj, {rotateZ: "360deg"}, {duration: 1000} ); }
             });
```

What may be the problem?

**UPDATE**

Codepen that demonstrates the issue: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYZaaj

Comment: This is how the transformations are made. In order to achieve what you want you need to first rotate the object and then move it. // OR, probably, Velocity.js allows you to specify rotation origin for the rotation?

Comment: I know that in CSS, "translate" is relative to the original location of the element, it does not actually move it, unlike "position" top and left. If it helps.

Comment: Also, in HTML5 Canvas there is an ability to `save` and `restore` context, thus "resetting" previous transformed origins. Maybe something similar is in `Velocity.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have enough points to comment, but hook (the other answer is right). Just add $.Velocity.hook(circle, "translateY", "0");

```js
var circle = $(".circle");

circle.velocity({
  translateX: 500,
  rotateZ: 360
}, {
  duration: 2500
}).delay(500).velocity({
  rotateZ: -360 * 2,
  translateY: 200
}, {
  duration: 2500
});
$.Velocity.hook(circle, "translateY", "0");

circle.delay(500)
  .velocity({
    translateY: 0,
    rotateZ: -360 * 5
  }, {
    duration: 2500
  });
```

```css
.circle {
  background: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16997159/square.png");
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.min.js"></script>

<div class="circle">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because Velocity currently does not parse initial `transform` values. From the docs:

> Note that Velocity's performance optimizations have the byproduct of ignoring outside changes to transform values (including initial values as defined in your stylesheets, but this is remedied via Forcefeeding). (You can manually set transform values within Velocity by using the Hook function.)

This will be addressed in future version but currently follow the advice below to use forcefeeding to fix it.

Comment: I don't think this relates to forcefeeding, but it relates to the rotation origin. What works for me: moving the element back to 0 using Velocity.hook, starting the animation, and again using Velocity.hook to move it to the desired position.

Comment: However I cannot get the both animations to work at the same time - I need to translate and rotate simultaneously.

Comment: Could you post a fiddle to explain exactly what you're seeing and what you're expecting?

Comment: Please take a look at the following codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYZaaj  First part of the animation is ok, however in the second and third parts of the animation the object is rotating in spiral, instead of rotating around its own center.